# EGit linked folder marked as dirty when its not

Tags: eclipse, egit

A linked folder In one of my projects is constantly marked as dirty.

The project belongs to another project that it also in my workspace that also uses EGit and is fully commited to date - with no files or folders marked as dirty.

The below shows what I am seeing in project explorer or navigator (each project also has other files and subdirs). How can I get PrjA to be clean tracked?

```
>PrjA (dirty because of linked subdir)
 |
 L> PrjBSubDir(linked, dirty)

PrjB (tracked, no changes)
 |
 L PrjBSubDir(tracked, no changes)
```

NOTE: I have Egit installed, but not git git, so I cant run prompt commands...

Comment: What version of EGit do you have installed?

Comment: @robinst v2.1.0.201209190230-r is this fixed in newer versions? When I run check for updates Egit is not listed, so I would be hesitant to force an update if there is not a proven fix. Especially as the Eclipse package (TI Code Composer Studio) I am using seems pretty temperamental...

Comment: @robinst I notice the changelog for 2.3 lists better handling for linked resources. Do you know if I update Egit, will I need to also update Mylynn? Before or after the Egit update? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it should be fixed in 2.3. See [What versions of Eclipse does EGit target](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F) for the minimum required version of the Eclipse platform. I'm not sure if Mylyn also needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated EGit and the issue was resolved.